# How to create a file -- including folders -- for a given path?

Tags: java, android, file

Am downloading a zip file from web. It contain folders and  files. Uncompressing them using `ZipInputstream` and `ZipEntry`. `Zipentry.getName` gives the name of file as `htm/css/aaa.htm`.

So I am creating new `File(zipentry.getName);`

But problem it is throwing an exception: `File not found`. I got that it is creating subfolders `htm` and `css`.

My question is: how to create a file including its sub directories, by passing above path?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Use this:

```
File targetFile = new File("foo/bar/phleem.css");
File parent = targetFile.getParentFile();
if (parent != null && !parent.exists() && !parent.mkdirs()) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Couldn't create dir: " + parent);
}
```

While you can just do `file.getParentFile().mkdirs()` without checking the result, it's considered a best practice to check for the return value of the operation. Hence the check for an existing directory first and then the check for successful creation (if it didn't exist yet).

Also, if the path doesn't include any parent directory, `parent` would be `null`. Check it for robustness.

**Reference:**

- [File.getParentFile()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile%28%29)
- [File.exists()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29)
- [File.mkdir()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29)
- [File.mkdirs()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29)

Comment: if i have a/b/c/d/e.txt. to create e.txt. i have to create a , b, , c,d folders. how can i get it ?

Comment: mkDir() only creates one level of parents, mkDirs() creates all parents, grandparents etc.

Comment: as I wrote: new File("a/b/c/d/e.txt").getParentFile().mkDirs() creates all needed folders, not just the parent folder

Comment: It should be `mkdirs` not `mkDirs`. Small 'd'.

Comment: changed that. so used to using autocompletion.

Comment: great reason for a downvote btw. who knows, maybe I also forgot a semicolon somewhere.

Answer (score 14):

You can use Google's [guava](/questions/tagged/guava) library to do it in a couple of lines with [Files](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#createParentDirs%28java.io.File%29) class:

```
Files.createParentDirs(file);
Files.touch(file);
```

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

Answer (score 6):

Java NIO API [Files.createDirectories](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectories(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...))

```java
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

Path path = Paths.get("/folder1/folder2/folder3");
Files.createDirectories(path);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create subdirectories if necessary, as you loop through the entries in the zip file.

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(myZipFile);
Enumeration e = zipFile.entries();
while(e.hasMoreElements()){
    ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry)e.nextElement();
    File destinationFilePath = new File(entry.getName());
    destinationFilePath.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    if(!entry.isDirectory()){
        //code to uncompress the file 
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but I'd do the folder creation inside the `if(!entry.isDirectory())` block, because you're creating all required parent folders anyway, so there's no need to do it when entry is a directory.

Answer (score 1):

Looks at the file you use the `.mkdirs()` method on a `File` object: http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-create-directory.shtml

```
        isDirectoryCreated = (new File("../path_for_Directory/Directory_Name")).mkdirs();
        if (!isDirectoryCreated) 
        {
            // Directory creation failed
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it

```
static void ensureFoldersExist(File folder) {
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        if (!folder.mkdirs()) {
            ensureFoldersExist(folder.getParentFile());
        }
    }
}
```